# How to make screenshot - html2canvas alternative reading css transform property

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, html2canvas

I have 2 images - one background and one image that I put into background. I want to merge these 2 images into one in the same position as they are. Second image should be rotated and resized.

Something like `html2canvas` but I need to use another method because `html2canvas` doesn't read css transform.

My current code is:

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('body').on('click', '.add-bomb', function(){
                var src = $(this).attr('src');
                $( ".bomb-overlay-holder" ).html('<img id="bomb-overlay">');
                $('.bomb-overlay-holder > img').attr('src',src);
                $( ".bomb-overlay-holder" ).draggable({ containment: ".background-bomb" });
                $( "#bomb-overlay" ).resizable({autoHide: true,containment: ".background-bomb"});
               
                $( "#bomb-overlay" ).parent().rotatable();
   });
});
```

```html
<div class="background-image-holder" id="background-image-holder">
                        <img src="<?php echo $bg_path;?>" class="background-bomb">
                        <span class="bomb-overlay-holder">
                        </span>
                    </div>
```

and I'm using `html2canvas` to make screenshot of images like that:

```js
html2canvas($("#background-image-holder") , {
      onrendered: function(canvas) {
                 var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
       }
  }
```

Comment: This question has been written 3 year. Nobody can answer it?